# How to get count of unique ids which have been assigned to only one value and no other?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

How to get for each value the count of ids which have been assigned to only one unique value and no other?

| date | country | value | id | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ---- | ----- | --a-- | 1 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --a-- | 2 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --b-- | 2 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --c-- | 2 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --d-- | 3 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --e-- | 4 | ----- |
| ---- | ----- | --e-- | 1 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --f-- | 2 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --g-- | 2 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --h-- | 2 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --i-- | 3 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --e-- | 4 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --j-- | 5 | ----- |
| ---- | ----- | --j-- | 1 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --a-- | 2 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --c-- | 2 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --d-- | 6 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --d-- | 3 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --e-- | 7 | ----- |
| ---- | ----- | --e-- | 1 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --f-- | 6 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --g-- | 2 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --z-- | 2 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --i-- | 3 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --g-- | 9 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --g-- | 10 | ----- |
| ----- | ----- | --k-- | 10 | ----- |

1. Example below, for value 'e' the result should be 2 (4 and 7 have only been assigned to one value and no other, which is 'e').
2. or for value 'b' the result should be 0 (no id has only been assigned to 'b' and no other value..)
3. or for value 'c' the result should be 0 (no id has only been assigned to 'c' and no other value..)
4. or for value 'j' the result should be 1 (5 has only been assigned to one value and no other, which is 'j')
5. or for value 'd' the result should be 1 (6 has only been assigned to one value and no other, which is 'd').
6. or for value 'g' the result should be 1 (9 has only been assigned to one value and no other, which is 'g').
7. etc......

Tried this but did not return right result.

```
    select  
    value
    , COUNT (distinct id)
    
    from table
    
    WHERE
    date >=  DATE '20200101'
        anD country IN (c1, c2, c3)
    
    group by
    value
   
    having
    max(value) LIKE 'a' AND min(value) LIKE 'a'
        OR max(value) LIKE 'b' AND min(value) LIKE 'b'
        OR max(value) LIKE 'c' AND min(value) LIKE 'c'
        OR max(value) LIKE 'd' AND min(value) LIKE 'd'
        OR max(value) LIKE 'e' AND min(value) LIKE 'e'
        OR max(value) LIKE 'f' AND min(value) LIKE 'f'
        OR max(value) LIKE 'g' AND min(value) LIKE 'g'
        etc... (rest of values / letters)
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to get for each value the count of ids which have been assigned to only one unique value and no other?

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select id
      from t
      group by id
      having min(value) = max(value)
     ) i;
```

Comment: I need for EACH value the count of ids which have been assigned only to that value.. Your SQL return only a number. The result for a specific value can also be 0, meaning for that value, no id has only been assigned to it. - BTW: WOW! Am I getting an answer from the real author of "Data Mining Techniques: For Marketing, Sales, and Customer Relationship"?

Comment: any help would be much appreciated!